# Magento 2 Get CMS page page_id from url

Tags: magento2, blocks, breadcrumbs, request

I simply want to get the CMS page id from a random url.

So i have a page with the url "Foo/Bar", and I can get the page id for that page using :

```
$pageId = $this->_request->getParam('page_id', $this->_request->getParam('id', false));
```

But now i want to have the page_id of "Foo". but ofcourse that is not requested so I can't use the getParam method.

What method should I use to get the page ID from a page where I only know the url of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **url_rewrite** table. Where you can search by request_path and use entity_id as your page Id.

Or try this if works for you.

```
protected $_page;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page,
    ...
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    ...
    $this->_page = $page;
    ...
}
    /**
     * Check if page identifier exist for specific store return page id if page exists
     *
     * @param string $identifier
     * @param int $storeId
     * @return int
     */
$page_id = $this->_page->checkIdentifier('home', 0);
if ($page_id > 0) {
    echo "Page Found";
}else {
    echo "Page Not Found";
}
```

Comment: I'd assume there is a more elegant solution for this problem, isn't there?

Comment: @Litsher-Nathan Updated. Please have a look.

Comment: You're a legend! Thanks man! :)